# Trying to use local-storage in react app, however not working in between pages

Tags: html, css, reactjs, local-storage, gatsby

I'm trying to save an array to local-storage in my react app, so that if the user goes to another page in the app, or closes the app and reopens it, the value stays the same.

In my index.js (simplified code):

```
import ls from 'local-storage';
function HomeIndex() {
  const [testString, setTestString] = useState(ls('localStorageText') || ''); 

  if(condition){
    const array = [1,2,3]; 
    const saveArray = {key: array}; 
    localStorage.setItem('key1', JSON.stringify(saveArray)); 
    const restoreValue = localStorage.getItem('key1');
    setTestString(JSON.parse(restoreValue).key);
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      {testString}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I press the button, and the condition is met, the `testString` value displays `123` as it should.  And it holds the value.  However it does not work when I try and add my own array.

```
const array = reversedHistoryText; 
const saveArray = {key: array}; 
localStorage.setItem('key1', JSON.stringify(saveArray)); 
const restoreValue = localStorage.getItem('key1');
setTestString(JSON.parse(restoreValue).key);
```

It doesn't display anything the first time the button is clicked, then gives error on the 2nd time:

```
Error: Minified React error #31;
```

When I do this test:

```
setTestString(JSON.stringify(reversedHistoryText));
```

The result is `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `testString` to the localStorage value.

```js
import ls from "local-storage";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTestArray(ls("testArray") || []);
  }, []);

  function handleClick(e) {
    ls("testArray", [
      { id: 1, name: "this" },
      { id: 2, name: "thing" },
      { id: 3, name: "is" },
      { id: 4, name: "cool" }
    ]);
    setTestArray(ls("testArray"));
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      <ul>
        {testArray.map(obj => (
          <p key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</p>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Set The State</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: When I try this `const [testString, setTestString] = useState(localStorage.getItem('localStorageText') || '');` and then build the project, I get the error:  `"localStorage" is not available during server side rendering.`

Comment: @baumli - I didn't know it was server-side rendered. I've updated the example to use the `local-storage` package you're using and to use `useEffect` to intialize the state after the component is mounted.

Comment: @Cory Larson - how do I do it if instead of the string 'TEST', its an array?

Comment: @baumli - Roughly the same way. I've updated the answer to use an array of objects instead.

Comment: @Cory Larson - I thought you couldn't directly assign an array to localstorage?

Comment: @baumli - You can using the `local-storage` package you were originally using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use third party for localStorage.

Just use localStorage without importing anything.

To save,

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

To get value from localStorage,

```
localStorage.getItem('key') // value
```

To remove value,

```
localStorage.removeItem('key')
```

Comment: What if the value is an array?  I can set it, but can't view it now.

Comment: Once it was saved to the localStorage, it's saved as string.
After get it, you need to restore it to original value.

Comment: So solution is that save it as object. and then restore it by using JSON.parse() and JSON.stringfy() function.

Comment: When I do this, it works:        
`const array = [1, 2, 3]; 
 const saveArray = {key: array};
 
        localStorage.setItem('key1', JSON.stringify(saveArray)); 
        const restoreValue = localStorage.getItem('key1');
        setTestString(JSON.parse(restoreValue).key);`
However when I add in my own array, it does not.

Comment: My array is reversedHistoryText:
`setReversedHistoryText(nextHistory.slice().reverse());`

Comment: Yes. it's okay with that reversedHistoryText. Just try it.

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't display anything on the screen, the second attempt throws an error 
`const array = reversedHistoryText;
 
const saveArray = {key: array}; 

localStorage.setItem('key1', JSON.stringify(saveArray));
 
const restoreValue = localStorage.getItem('key1');

setTestString(JSON.parse(restoreValue).key);`

Error: `Error: Minified React error #31;`

Comment: This is not related error with localStorage. Try to print localStorage value in console and try check if it works.

Comment: If I do this: 
`const array = reversedHistoryText; 
        const saveArray = {key: array}; 
        localStorage.setItem('key1', JSON.stringify(saveArray)); 
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('key1'));`
 
then I get this in my console: `{"key":[]}`

Comment: Try to check if your reversedHistoryText is empty array.

Comment: You may be on to something, because if I click again, it shows my array, but only the first entry, not both.  Should I be doing a promise on it to make sure it runs before continuing?

Comment: Yes, maybe. There should be data before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(condition) ls('localStorageText', "TEST");
setTestString(ls('localStorageText')|| ' '); }
```

Instead

```
if(condition){ ls('localStorageText', "TEST");
 setTestString(ls('localStorageText')); }
```

Because when you go back to the index page a new instance of this component is rendered and i think the condition in the if statement is false, so the code don't change the setstate value...

Answer (score 0):

To set use

```
localStorage.setItem('itemName', JSON.stringify(arrayName));
```

To get use

```
whatEver = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('itemName'));
```

Local storage stores strings